# is there a way to send multiple images to an API at the same time fastapi

Tags: python-3.x, rest, dictionary, python-requests, fastapi

I need to hit the fastapi with multiple images

```
@app.post("/text")
def get_text(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
```

its working when I try uploading multiple images using /docs interface, I tried with one file its working fine here is the code for it

```
import requests
import json
def get_text(image_path):
    #images={}
    url = 'http://address/text'
    try:
        with open(image_path, "rb") as im:
            image_data={"files":im}
            response=requests.post(url,files=image_data)
            return json.loads(response.text)
    except Exception as er:
        print("error occured")
        return "{} error occured".format(er)
```

when I tried adding more images to the image_data but i am getting error.

```
image_data ={"files":[]}
for image in image_list:
    with open(image, "rb") as im:
        image_data['files'].append(im)
```

tried above code but no use.

error message after running the above
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcqQa.png)

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the solution , its not the problem of fastapi , its related to requests library

Incase any one  needs  the solution here it is

```
files = [
        ('files', ('image1', open('/Users/ai/image1.jpg','rb'), 'image/png')),
        ('files', ('image2', open('/Users/ai/image2.jpeg','rb'), 'image/png'))
        ]
```

you can use the below function for multiple files

```
import requests
import json

def get_text(image_list,url):
    try:
        image_data=[]
        for image in image_list:
            image_data.append(('files',(image.split('/')[-1],open(image,'rb'),'image/png')))#('files',(image_name,open image,type))
        response=requests.post(url,files=image_data)
        return json.loads(response.text)
    except Exception as er:
        print("error occured")
        return "{} error occured".format(er)
```

You can check docs [Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)

Thanks..!